# How to get bucket name from Bucket object in AWS CDK for python

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cdk

I've create an S3 bucket for hosting my website. For that I've used the below code from the AWS CDK for python docs

```py
self.bucket = s3.Bucket(
    self,
    "my-bucket-name",
    bucket_name="my-bucket-name",
    removal_policy=core.RemovalPolicy.DESTROY,
    website_index_document="index.html",
    public_read_access=True
)
```

For a reason, I want to send this bucket object as an argument to another object and get the bucket name from the argument. So, I've tried

```
self.bucket.bucket_name
self.bucket.bucket_arn
```

nothing seems working, instead the object returns `${Token[TOKEN.189]}`. Could anyone guide me through this?

Comment: Can you share the code for the other object you're creating that needs the bucket name?

Comment: @maafk It doesn't matter, because I'm getting the same output even if I just do `print(f"Bucket Name", self.bucket.bucket_name)` right below the above code

Comment: Where are you printing the bucket name, bucket_name should give you the name, if you use self.bucket.bucket_name on another object then run CDK synth and look at your template you should see that it is using the reference to your bucket, I don't think you should be able to print the bucket name in cdk before generating the template can you, at that point it is only a reference

Comment: @AnonymousAlias right. Thanks mate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the bucket name is hard coded like the example you pasted above, you can always externalize it to the cdk context file.  As you've seen, when you access the bucket name from the Bucket construct, it creates a reference to it and that is so if you need it in another resource, cloud formation will depend on the value from the Bucket resource by using the Ref/GetAtt capabilities in CloudFormation.  Then it will be guaranteed that the bucket actually exists before it is used downstream.

If you don't care about that and just want the actual bucket name in the cdk app code then put the value in the cdk context json file and use node.try_get_context to retrieve it wherever.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I guess that's the only way, I will change my code

Answer (score 4):

There is a handy method called `fromBucketName` you can use:

```js
const bucket = aws_s3.Bucket.fromBucketName(this, "bucketLabel", "nameYouGaveBucket")
```

Otherwise, I believe you are looking for `bucket.bucketName` (typescript) or `bucket.bucket_name` (python).

See [typescript docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_s3.Bucket.html#static-fromwbrbucketwbrnamescope-id-bucketname) [python docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/python/aws_cdk.aws_s3/Bucket.html#aws_cdk.aws_s3.Bucket.from_bucket_name). This is also available in the CDK wrappers in other languages.

Note that there are similar methods for all sorts of CDK constructs, so you should refer often to the API docs, as there is lots like this you can find easily there.

Comment: What's the difference between the bucketLabel and the bucket name? I don't seem to find a clear distinction anywhere

Comment: `bucketLabel` is just an identifier for the construct you are instantiating in CDK, whereas `bucketName` is the name of the bucket resource you provision on AWS--the one you would use for specifying the resource in CLI commands, S3 urls, etc. This id is a big more logical when working with constructs that generate a number of resources, e.g. `ecs.FargateService(this, 'MyFargateService', { cluster, taskDefinition })`.